# ajaxSetup not working with Rails / jquery-ujs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ujs

I'm working on a project that makes heavy usage of XHR, and there is some data that needs to be appended to each ajax request in order for the server side to properly keep track of what is going on in the browser.

I have a generic class called xhr_response_handler than I use to handle the callbacks for all ajax requests that is added to all forms, links etc that is making ajax requests. (i.e. where ":remote => true" in rails)

```
$('.xhr_response_handler')
    .on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) { xhr_success(data); })
    .on('ajax:failure', function(xhr, status, error) { xhr_fail(error); });
```

Then I try to append the default data sent with each request using:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        Foo: <%= @Bar %>
    }
});
```

This works for some of the elements where the ajax settings are configured directly with jquery, but this does not work for some elements created using rails methods like link_to and form_for with :remote => true.

The odd thing is that if I also add

```
$('.xhr_response_handler').data( 'params', { Foo2: <%= @Bar2 %> } );
```

Then that works for adding data to the rails generated ajax requests using link_to. What makes it odd is that now all of a sudden the ajaxSettings also works, and in the ajax requests I get both Foo and Foo2 as parameters. But I get no parameters at all when using ajaxSettings by itself.

Furthermore, none of the data to be appended gets serialized into the form data sent in ajax requests generated from the rails form_for method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Rails 3.2.3

Ruby 1.9.3p194

jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this behaviour appears because the data hash of `$.ajaxSetup` is overridden by the ajax calls you do later on. The data has to be merged manually.